# Setting QListWidget Minimum Height

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I've got a widget with a vertical layout. That widget is vertically split and its children are another QWidget and a QListWidget. The splitter is not set to collapse its children and the list widget has a minimum height of 0. Even with no items in the list widget, I can't use the splitter to make the list widget get any smaller than around 70px, vertically. I can manually set the maximum height to under 70px and it will obey.

I figured out that least that it's not my program specifically because I tried a fresh layout in Qt Designer and the same thing happens even in preview mode (bottom area is the QListWidget):

[image: Qt Designer preview]

I've also tried manually setting the sizeHint for the items to under that imaginary limit. The width is respected but the height stays the same.

Comment: When you say the QSplitter is not set to collapse its children, do you mean you *have* set it to *not* collapse them? QSplitter collapses by default.

Comment: Right, I set the childrenCollapsible property of the QSplitter to false.

Comment: Have you tried setting not only minimum height, but also minimumSizeHint?

Comment: There actually is no way to set minimumSizeHint explicitly, but looking for that actually led me to the answer, which I've posted below. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the QListWidget's vertical size policy to "Ignored". I can't say I understand why having a minimum width of zero isn't respected.